# Sportsmanship badge competing

Tags: support, badges, sportsmanship-badge

So lets say I answer a question and get +1. If there are 7 other answers competing do I get 7 counts towards my progress or only 1 if I upvote all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know.

But if you are a true sportsman (or -woman), it won't matter to you in the first place.

One would simply upvote all contributions that are *worth* upvoting.

One should never blindly upvote every other answer just to get closer to the badge.

Comment: but..but...but I just want the badge. :)